# Как распарсить json с помощью gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Всем привет, у меня есть String, и в нем записан массив json, 
вида:

```
[{name:Vlad,family:Smith},{name:Masha,family:Johnson}]
```

Мне нужно получить массив объектов, как это сделать с помощью библиотеки gson?

Comment: JSON у вас, к слову, не валидный.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<MyClass> list = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>(){}.getType());
```